# Swift PDFKit add annotation to beginning of page annotation array?

Tags: swift

In Swift PDFKit is there a way to add an annotation to to the beginning of the page annotations array. I want to add my annotation to the beginning of the array because it is an image and I have other annotations I want to be able to edit that are ontop of it.

The only way I can find to add an annotation is with the following, but it adds it to the end of the array overlaying all other annotations that need to be editable.

```
page.addAnnotation(myannotation)
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a terrible solution, but it works . . .

I made a tmp list of all the annotations, remove all annotations on the page, and then added them all back with the image added first.

```
let list = page.annotations
for i in page.annotations{
    page.removeAnnotation(i)
}
// add myannotation first
page.addAnnotation(myannotation)
// add other annotations back
for i in list {
    page.addAnnotation(i)
}
```